# SSRS parameter for multiple value GUIDs used in query throws odd error but works when I manually put GUIDs in the query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My query used in an SSRS report:

```
SELECT DISTINCT      
    asm.AssemblyCode,
    asm.AssemblyRestorationDesc,
    asm.AssemblyUnit,
    asm.AssemblyGuid,
    (SELECT SUM(m.MarkerQuantity) 
     FROM Marker m 
     WHERE m.AssemblyGuid = asm.AssemblyGuid
       AND m.MarkerExcludeFromScope = 'False'
       AND m.ContractGuid IN (@Contract)                    
       AND m.Deleted = 0) AS Quantity,
    (SELECT SUM(smkr.MarkerQuantity) 
     FROM BaselineMarker smkr  
     WHERE smkr.AssemblyCode = asm.AssemblyCode
       AND smkr.MarkerExcludeFromScope = 'False'
       AND smkr.Deleted = 0) AS BaselineQuantity,
    (SELECT SUM(sa.AllowanceQuantity) 
     FROM BaselineAllowance sa
     WHERE sa.AssemblyCode = asm.AssemblyCode
       AND sa.Deleted = 0) AS AllowanceQuantity
FROM 
    Assembly asm
WHERE 
    asm.Deleted = 0
ORDER BY 
    asm.AssemblyCode, asm.AssemblyRestorationDesc, asm.AssemblyUnit, asm.AssemblyGuid
```

Throws an odd error that isn't really making sense given that the report works if I select a single value for the `@Contract` parameter instead of multiple values, which tells me the parameter itself is set up fine. Also, if I set the parameter itself to a single value parameter instead of calling multiple values, it works fine too.

The report also works if I manually enter the GUIDs by replacing the line `AND m.ContractGuid IN (@Contract)` with:

```
AND m.ContractGuid IN ('60A38AD0-F24F-DF11-A19C-00111103CDB5', 'F8C018CA-A00C-4BB1-B920-D460786F6820')
```

Could the parameter not be returning a list in the correct format?

Nothing should be odd about the parameter. It's Name is Contract, its prompt is Contract, its data type is text, it allows multiple values, the values are taken from a simple query. The return value is the contract guid, and the return prompt is the contract name.

The error I get is:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> Query execution failed for dataset 'RestorationSummary'.
> (rsErrorExecutingCommand) Must declare the scalar variable
> "@Contract". Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. Incorrect syntax
> near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: I'm not sure what could cause this. Typically this message would be seen if the report parameter name and the t-sql variable name did not match (case sensitive) but the must or I would expect the single value to fail. Also make sure that the strings do not include quotes or anything else that should not be part of the guid. After making sure that this is multi-value, the next thing I would do is run a trace and see what query is actually being passed to the server. That might at least throw some light on it.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason for this to happen either. The only thing I could think of to try would be to CONVERT your GUID for the Contract parameter dataset to a VARCHAR.

Comment: Solved it. Typo error on my part that I didn't notice. The @Contract parameter name was missing the @ in the queries' parameter list. I would have looked at that a little more closely, except selecting a single value had worked somehow.